# update an image in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update an image of both the folder where they are uploaded and the db but the problem that the code that I have does not appear to me, only the error script when updating the data is what I get because I put it on , but it does not show me the error of why the image is not updated. Please, if you can help me-

Form to update

```
<form action="actualizarimg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php while($registro=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $registro['nombre']; ?>">
<img height="200px" src="./<?php echo $registro['ruta_imagen']; ?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $registro['ruta_imagen'];?>"
<label for="img">Imágen</label>
<input type="file"> <p>Subir Archivo</p> 
<label>Descripción</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $registro['descripcion']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Actualizar">
</form>
```

Code to update

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
if(isset($_GET['cve_imagen'])){
    $cve_imagen=$_GET['cve_imagen'];
}
  if(isset($_GET['nombre'])){
    $nombre=$_GET['nombre'];
  }
  if(isset($_GET['descripcion'])){
    $descripcion=$_GET['descripcion'];
  }
   if(isset($_GET['ruta_imagen'])){
    $ruta_imagen=$_GET['ruta_imagen'];

$sql = "UPDATE imagenes SET nombre='$nombre', descripcion='$descripcion', ruta_imagen='$ruta_imagen' WHERE cve_imagen='$cve_imagen' ";
print_r($conexion);
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('Los datos se actualizaron exitosamente');
window.location='eliminar.php';
</script>";
 }else {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('Error al actualizar los datos');
window.location='eliminar.php';
</script>";

 }
 $conexion->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: first you sending your form with POST method. And you check variables with GET method... Second you don't have any code to execute any action on the file. Take a look here for more information in $_FILES to start : http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: You have also not named any of your form fields.